# How do you create separation between JMenuBar and JToolbar

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar, jtoolbar

i am trying to add Separate between the `JMenuBar` and `JToolBar` because it's coming like their are no space between `JMenuBar` and `JToolBar` for example can i make `JToolBar` bold or something

```
JPanel addTable = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
addTable.add(table,BorderLayout.NORTH);
addTable.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

Container cp=getContentPane();
cp.add(addTable);
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _"Sharing Living"_?

Comment: you can take look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MatteBorder` for the `JToolBar` and just set the top edge

```
JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("ToolBar");
MatteBorder matteBorder = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
toolBar.setBorder(matteBorder);
```

This will give you a line on top of the tool bar, one pixel color black

[image]

Disregard the complete image. Its just some code I had handy with a menu bar in it.

Notice the line at the top of the toolbar to give more distinction in separation. You can play around with the pixel thickness and color. If you want it a little more subtle, tou can use a color like light_gray or gray. Your choice

See [MatteBorder javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/MatteBorder.html)

Comment: is this method from the absolute position because i don't like to use like this layout

Comment: No there's no need to use a layout just to set the border. The picture is just my example. All you need to do is set the border of the toolbar to the MatteLayout. Look at my code. That's all you need. You don't need to change anything else.

Comment: thanks it's work but can i do this in other way like playing in the JPanel just looking for more information

Comment: There's no point in using a JPanel. There _are_ ways though. If you're _really_ interested, take a look at the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Another option if you just want separation with _no_ line, you can use an EmptyBorder: `EmptyBorder border = new EmptyBorder(3, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

also there are some tutorial for JPanel Border here 
[Border tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#code)